# MSVC gives warning C26478 "using std::move on constant variables"

Tags: c++

I have the following code that returns a [warning C26478](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26478?view=msvc-170) with MSVC 1937 (with `/W4`). However both clang and gcc (with `-Wpedantic -Wextra -Wall`) are fine with this code.

```
std::tuple<int, int> i_make_tuples(){
    return std::make_tuple(42,23);
}

int main() {
    auto const [x,y] = i_make_tuples(); // C26478 (Don't use std::move on constant variables) reported here
}
```

Am I wrong or is this warning unjustified in this case?

Comment: You're not wrong, but try `const auto &`.

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug.

Comment: Yes, the `&` makes the warning go away. But declaring a reference as const seems a bit redundant...

Comment: @user2393256: you can't declare the reference `const`; you'll be declaring a reference-**to**-const. This then gives you lifetime extension, which is why it works even though notionally you'll have a reference to a no-longer-alive temporary.

Comment: @You That is interesting, but i am not sure if i understand. Why would this extend the lifetime?

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/vvY7vz3a3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a false positive, which has been [acknowledged as a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-C26478-warning-when-using-structur/10417562) by the MSVC developers.

Comment: @user2393256 feel free to accept the answer if you think it answered your question.